# Adding a FileDownload Control by library control

Tags: jsf, xpages

I am trying to build an JSF library control for XPages based on the examples by Keith Strickland.

http://xprentice.gbs.com/A55BAC/keithstric.nsf/default.xsp?documentId=82770C11FA7B9B21852579C100581766

I'm having a little bit trouble in building a FileDownloadControl
Here is the code I've built:

```
     public class Libcontrol extends UIComponentBase implements FacesComponent {

        private static final String RENDERER_TYPE = "de.chris.Libcontrol ";
        private static final String COMPONENT_FAMILY = "de.chris";

        public Libcontrol() {
                setRendererType(RENDERER_TYPE);
        }

        @Override
        public String getFamily() {
                return COMPONENT_FAMILY;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void initBeforeContents(FacesContext arg0) throws FacesException {


            FacesContext context;
            ExpressionEvaluatorImpl evaluator;

        
            context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            evaluator = new ExpressionEvaluatorImpl(context);

        
            XspFileDownload result = new XspFileDownload();
            String sourceId = "fileDownload1/@value";
            String valueExpr = "#{document1.FileField}";
            ValueBinding value = evaluator.createValueBinding(result, valueExpr, sourceId,Object.class);
            result.setValueBinding("value", value);
            result.setDisplayLastModified(true);
            result.setAllowDelete(true);
            result.setTitle("filedown");
            result.setRows(30);
            result.setId("fileDownload1");

            this.getChildren().add(result);


        }

        public void buildContents(FacesContext arg0, FacesComponentBuilder arg1) throws FacesException {
        // Do Nothing
        }

       
        public void initAfterContents(FacesContext arg0) throws FacesException {
        // Do nothing
        }
}
```

Why is the control not completely rendered? When I look to the HTML Code I see a starttag from the control but no Files to download
and yes I've uploaded files to the corresponding NotesDocument.

Here is the renderer I have implmented respectively copied:

```
public class MainLibcontrolRenderer extends Renderer {


@Override
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
    try {
        super.encodeBegin(context, component);
        context =  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        UIViewRootEx rootEx = (UIViewRootEx) context.getViewRoot();
        /*rootEx.setDojoParseOnLoad(true);
        rootEx.setDojoTheme(true);*/
        
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.startElement("fieldset", component);
        
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 

@Override
public void encodeChildren(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
    try {
        
        super.encodeChildren(context, component);      
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 

@Override
public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
    try {
        super.encodeEnd(context, component);
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.endElement("fieldset");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: buildContents // Do Nothing ?

Comment: this is my first time Im creating a component like this. Do i have to write something in this method?

Comment: I have to ask, what are you trying to accomplish here? I ask because I see you have a hard coded field name in the ValueBinding above. This defeats the purpose of putting a component in a plugin library. You put a component in a plugin to make it available for all the developers on a server to use and having the hard coded ValueBinding defeats that purpose.

Also, if you're building an application from the library, I recommend doing that the traditional XPages way and including any REST services, components and associated classes in the library and business logic within the nsf.

Comment: This is only a example of what Im trying to do. The hard coded valubinding, id, and so on will be replaced in my application. My problem is that I have no idea why the filedownload is not rendered. I'm searching for a advice what I have to do or simple of an idea what is wrong in what I have done

Answer (score 0):

Stephan is right: the reason the contents do not render is that you're not building them. When implementing FacesComponent, the buildContents method typically should instruct the FacesComponentBuilder to initiate the build process; e.g.:

```
arg1.buildAll(arg0, this, true);
```

NOTE: I'm using the argument names from your example; ideally, you should use meaningful argument names like "context" and "builder".

The buildAll method referred to above causes the component tree to properly reflect any changes made to the structure during the init methods. If you skip this step, the subsequent JSF phases (including RENDER_RESPONSE) are unaware of any components you injected.

By the way, Keith also makes a valid point: hardcoding the value binding and other properties - at least, in the example you provided - tends to defeat the purpose of defining a reusable control. I'd echo Keith's advice to take a closer look at what you're trying to accomplish to determine whether a custom component is really the appropriate implementation. And one final caution: use extreme care when programmatically setting the id property on injected components... you could end up with a name collision that cannot be detected during compilation. In other words, Designer can't warn you... it will just break at runtime and the reason for failure will probably not be obvious.

Comment: As I wrote above this is only an example of what I am trying to do, not the finla code for my control. 
I added your codeline to the buildcontents method but nothing happens. should I add anything else or change/add more than I expect?

Comment: I'm unable to determine from what you've posted thus far what renderer you're using for the component. When you extend an existing component, it typically just uses the renderer for the base component unless you define your own. Have you created and defined a custom renderer for this component?

Comment: I have added my renderer to my Question text. I hope that explains a little bit better what ive done or tryed to do^^. I have added my own custom renderer and defined a config file. Also I have published it in the faces config

Comment: You've mentioned that this is only an example of the idea, not the actual feature you intend to implement... but a key reason that it's difficult to troubleshoot your issue is that the example you've posted doesn't really add anything not already available in the core control. In fact, it actually reduces functionality, since you're assigning hardcoded values to properties that could otherwise be assigned different values or value bindings on each page. If you post a more representative example of what you're trying to accomplish, the nature of the problem might be easier to identify.

Comment: OK the whole idea is to build an control that creates a set of controls from a XML config. From this configuration there should be all standart IBM control like Inputtext, richtext, fieldupload s.o. one of the controls should be a fileDownload. I the method "initBeforeContents" I have orginally build some code to read a config an then build the controls in a XSPTable. So and now my only Problem is tha all contols work fine without the filedownload.